# Put plus, minus, time and divide sign in a square

Tags: graphics, symbols, math-operators, characters

For circumscribed circle, it is `$\otimes$`, `$\ominus$`, I get it, but how do you put them inside a square?

i have seen something similar in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228440/how-to-put-a-character-inside-a-square) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256869/alternative-otimes-to-use-with-euler-math).

Comment: What do you want to achieve that is not covered by the questions you link to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loading the `amssymb` package, you can use some commands

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\boxtimes$ \par
$\boxplus$ \par
$\boxminus$ \par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Alenanno. how about the divide operation?